Rocket payload calculator for initial velocity and altitude
Background
I'm looking to develop a calculator similar to this one, to help me tweak a rocket's rough characteristics and determine its maximum payload.
The rocket is accelerated inside an evacuated launch ring to Mach 7 then ejected at ~6000 m, destined for orbit at ~400 km.
I'd like to tweak most of the input values (below) to determine whether a small rocket could make it into a given orbit, and how much of a payload the rocket could carry.
Assumptions

The nosecone can withstand the heat.
The air is sufficiently thin that the rocket can survive initial contact with the air when transitioning out of the vacuum unscathed.
The fuel is solid metallic hydrogen ($1.15 g/cm^3$). Don't get hung up on this aspect: it can simply be another input value to the calculator (e.g., fuel mass).

Inputs
To get a decent estimate for the maximum payload, the calculator  needs at least:

a starting elevation (6212 m)
a starting velocity (Mach 7)
an orbital altitude (400 km)
surface temperature (25 C) (to derive air density at elevation)
specific impulse (1700 s)
wet mass (250 kg)
dimensions (e.g., length [4 m?], diameter [0.5 m])
drag coefficient (0.75)
latitude (1.469167)

Equations

Convert latitude to rotational velocity (boosts $\Delta v$)

$S = \frac{2 \pi \times R_e \times cos( \alpha ))}{23.934472 hr}$; $R_e$ is Earth radius, $\alpha$ is latitude in degrees.


Tsiolkovsky rocket equation

$\Delta v = I_{sp} \times g_0 \times ln \frac{m_0}{m_f}$; $I_{sp}$ is effective exhaust velocity, $g_0$ is gravity, $m_0$ is wet mass, $m_f$ is dry mass.


Air pressure

$P = P_{sea} \times ​\big(1− \frac{0.0065h}{0.0065h+T+273.15}​\big)^{5.257}$


Air density

$\rho = \frac{P}{R(T+273.15)}$; $P$ is atmospheric pressure, $T$ is temperature in Celsius, $R$ is unique gas constant.


Drag force

$F_D = C_d \times \frac{\rho \times V^2}{2} A$; $C_d$ is drag coefficient, $\rho$ is air density, $V$ is velocity, $A$ is cross-section area.


Gravitational force

$F = G_0 \times \frac{(m_1 \times m_2)}{r^2}$; $G_0$ is gravity, $m_1$ is Earth mass, $m_2$ is rocket mass, $r$ is distance.


Centripetal force

$F_c = \frac{(m_2 \times v^2)}{r}$; $m_2$ is rocket mass, $v$ is orbital velocity, $r$ is distance.


Orbital velocity

$v = \sqrt{\frac{G_0 \times m_1}{r}}$, $v$ is final velocity, $G_0$ is gravity, $m_1$ is Earth mass, $r$ is distance.



Reaching a LEO altitude of 400 km needs a velocity of 7,672 meters per second.
Question
Beyond those listed, what other equations are necessary to make a calculator that can help compute the maximum payload mass that such a small-sized rocket could include while still reaching the desired orbital altitude?
Bonus question
How do I calculate the time the rocket would take to reach its orbit?

Metallic hydrogen requires fuel storage pressures in excess of 1 million atmospheres ($10^{12}$ Pa). https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Phase_diagram_of_hydrogen.png

"Metallic hydrogen is predicted to be metastable, meaning it will remain metallic if the pressure is released." source.  The calculator will allow for any specific impulse value to be used, making the type of fuel moot with respect to the question.

Here are a few equations which you might find handy: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/k-12/airplane/specimp.html In addition, this video shows you how to calculate how long a hohmann transfer works, which is probably important for your calculator
